Check if a conid is available for you to trade in ib web api
I am trying to find a way to check if you can trade an asset. So I need to find if I have market access for a specific conid (and exchange). But the only way I can find right now is to query for historical market data, which seems extremely inefficient. Is there another way to do it?
